# All tasks finish but dataproc spark job does not conclude

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc, dataproc

I am running a spark dataproc job. Everything in the code finishes. I have `print('savedddd'); print(scores)` as the ultimate last line of my code and it executes as well.
[image]
All the activity on all nodes goes to 0. Yet the  dataproc job does not conclude. My shell prints `22/01/13 19:29:15 INFO org.sparkproject.jetty.server.AbstractConnector: Stopped Spark@a69cfdd{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:0}` and that's it. The terminal remains stuck there. In the jobs tab, the job constantly shows as running and I have to manually cancel it. [image]

Could you help me debug the issue?

As instructed by @Igor I have tried to use jstack. My attempts are following:

1. Ran `sudo jps -mlvV`
2. Relevant pid is 14961
3. I ran `sudo jstack -l 14961`

output:

```
Full thread dump OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.292-b10 mixed mode):
"DestroyJavaVM" #657 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f9bd8013800 nid=0x3a83 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
"pool-42-thread-1" #360 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f9b90582000 nid=0x3eb2 waiting on condition [0x00007f9b6b24b000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x0000000094d52ac0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
        at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
"yarn-scheduler-endpoint" #261 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f9bd9d61000 nid=0x3dab waiting on condition [0x00007f9b6f185000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x0000000088bf5dd0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
        at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
"client DomainSocketWatcher" #54 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f9b919d1800 nid=0x3ae3 runnable [0x00007f9b84ee1000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.unix.DomainSocketWatcher.doPoll0(Native Method)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.unix.DomainSocketWatcher.access$900(DomainSocketWatcher.java:52)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.unix.DomainSocketWatcher$2.run(DomainSocketWatcher.java:503)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"Service Thread" #7 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f9bd80cb800 nid=0x3a8c runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
"C1 CompilerThread1" #6 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f9bd80c7000 nid=0x3a8b waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
"C2 CompilerThread0" #5 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f9bd80c4000 nid=0x3a8a waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
"Signal Dispatcher" #4 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f9bd80c1000 nid=0x3a89 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f9bd808b800 nid=0x3a88 in Object.wait() [0x00007f9bc5e87000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:144)
        - locked <0x00000000881de630> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:165)
        at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:216)
"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f9bd8087000 nid=0x3a87 in Object.wait() [0x00007f9bc5f88000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
        at java.lang.ref.Reference.tryHandlePending(Reference.java:191)
        - locked <0x00000000881de800> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:153)
"VM Thread" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f9bd807d800 nid=0x3a86 runnable 
"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f9bd8029000 nid=0x3a84 runnable 
"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f9bd802a800 nid=0x3a85 runnable 
"VM Periodic Task Thread" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f9bd80ce800 nid=0x3a8d waiting on condition 
JNI global references: 7697
Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 542720K, used 445168K [0x00000000d8000000, 0x00000000ff300000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 439296K, 93% used [0x00000000d8000000,0x00000000f0f809d0,0x00000000f2d00000)
  from space 103424K, 34% used [0x00000000f8e00000,0x00000000fb13b870,0x00000000ff300000)
  to   space 99328K, 0% used [0x00000000f2d00000,0x00000000f2d00000,0x00000000f8e00000)
 ParOldGen       total 542208K, used 248894K [0x0000000088000000, 0x00000000a9180000, 0x00000000d8000000)
  object space 542208K, 45% used [0x0000000088000000,0x000000009730f8c8,0x00000000a9180000)
 Metaspace       used 145492K, capacity 160872K, committed 161152K, reserved 1189888K
  class space    used 19087K, capacity 20303K, committed 20352K, reserved 1048576K
2022-01-20 19:48:51
Full thread dump OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.292-b10 mixed mode):
```

Comment: To understand what is holding your job you need to capture stack trace of the Spark driver process using `jstack` command. May you share it?

Comment: Thank you for your response @IgorDvorzhak . The final pyspark statement in my code was ```df.write.format("csv").save("example.csv")```. The python statements after this line were executing but the job was not sending [DONE] status when all was said and done. I changed it to ```df.write.csv("example.csv")``` and it started concluding the job just fine. Do you still want me to post the driver stack trace? I can change the line back to ```df.write.format("csv").save("example.csv")``` and post it.

Comment: No, if you fixed an issue, you can post it as an answer and accept it :)

Comment: Sure. I will. But, I have absolutely no idea why that fixed the issue though. One would think that the two ways to write the csv to the storage would just be a difference of API and would map to exact same mechanism. This was odd

Comment: @IgorDvorzhak - Apparently the error resolving had nothing to do with me having changed the spark.write call. It was luck only without it being the cause. The issue is still there. It just happens erratically. Can you please tell me how to use jstack to provide you with further information. As I see it jstack uses pid. How do I get the relevant pid for spark running on driver?

Comment: You can get pid using `sudo jps -mlvV` command - after that you need to find a driver process and its pid and use `jstack`

Comment: @IgorDvorzhak - I have updated the question to include the information that I think you are asking for. Can you please check it and guide me further?

Comment: Interesting, do not see anything suspicious in the stack trace. Can you repro the same via calling `spark-submit` directly, or only via Dataproc Jobs API?

Comment: Have I used the correct pid? There are many provided as the output to ```sudo jps -mlvV```. For example, there is also ```30837 org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit --name PySparkShell pyspark-shell -Dscala.usejavacp=true -Xmx1920m``` . If you suggest we can move this to a chat

Comment: Seems so, `30837` PID seems to be for `pyspark` CLI.

Comment: well, the job is still running as we speak. The ```INFO org.sparkproject.jetty.server.AbstractConnector: Stopped Spark@629626a0{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:0}``` message showed up about 20 minutes ago. Everything has run in my code but the console is still showing the job as running. Shall I try to submit this by moving my code to master node and then use ```spark-submit```?

There are quite a few threads in ```os.wait()``` and ```waiting on condition``` state in the trace that I pasted above. Is that okay?

Comment: @IgorDvorzhak I was able to replicate it using ```spark-submit```. I opened another terminal on master and ran ```jstack -l pid```. On the terminal I ran it I get ```14961: Unable to open socket file: target process not responding or HotSpot VM not loaded
The -F option can be used when the target process is not responding``` however, the output gets printed on the terminal where the job is stuck. I am updating the question with the output. Can you please give it a look

Comment: @IgorDvorzhak I think I had mistakenly pasted only half the output of ```jstack```. This time I have ensured that the full stack is reported. Hoping this time it reveals something

Comment: In the stack trace you can see `pool-42-thread-1` non-daemon thread that blocking program shutdown because it's not daemon. You need to check if your app code creates any threads/executors with non daemon threads.

Comment: Can you help me with checking if my app creates any threads/executors with non-daemon threads? I have not interacted with threading explicitly at all. I have just used pyspark and synapseml. Moreover, sometimes it hangs sometimes it runs. So, I am lost for ways to proceed. What do you suggest?

Comment: As a temp fix, I raise a ValueError as the final line of my code. This seems to always shut the job. Do you see any problems with that?

Comment: Aren't this will make job to fail? Or ValueError marks it as successful? You can try to explicitly [stop SparkContext](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#stop--) at the end of your job, if this is a Spark-managed thread then it could fix the issue.

Comment: The job will fail. But, I am raising the error as the last line of my code so everything that I wanted to achieve from the job has been achieved anyway. It does result in a failed status in the console. Explicitly stopping the ```SparkSession``` did not work and still results in the issue. I expected that as even without me explicitly stopping the SparkSession, stopping SparkSession is the last thing that the job does and prints ```INFO org.sparkproject.jetty.server.AbstractConnector: Stopped Spark@2fa51314{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:0}``` .  Please see the image of terminal I have attached

Comment: Raising an error is not graceful though. Can I do something else to force the non-daemon thread to close?

Comment: At the end of your PySpark code you can call `sys.exit(0)` - it should force graceful driver exit: https://python101.pythonlibrary.org/chapter20_sys.html#sys-exit

Comment: Tried. Unfortunately, it still hangs :|

Comment: This looks like an issue in the app code/dependencies - you may want to try to narrow-down problem by using just one dependency/library at a time, and when you identify what library usage leads to hanging, you can file an issue with them on GitHub, etc.